# How to delete database row in this php script

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a situation with my php code. What I am currently doing is using the iframe to link the javascript message with the phe script. In the javascript function stopImageUpload, I have stated that if success = 2, then display the cancel message for the file upload.

So what I have tried but failed to do in the php script is to try and state that if the $result = 2 (In other words if success = 2 message appears in javascript), then delete the database row. How can this be done?

Below is the form code:

```
var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='return imageClickHandler(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" + 
  "Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/><br/><label class='imagelbl'>" + 
  "<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label>" +     
  "</p><p class='imagef1_cancel' align='center'><label>" + 
  "<input type='button' name='imageCancel' class='imageCancel' value='Cancel' /></label>" +
  "<iframe class='upload_target' name='upload_target' src='#' style='width:0;height:0;border:0px;solid;#fff;'></iframe></form>");
```

Below is the startImageUpload() function where it starts an file upload and where the cancel button function is stored:

```
  function startImageUpload(imageuploadform, imagefilename){
    $('.imagef1_cancel').eq(window.lastUploadImageIndex).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {
      return stopImageUpload(2);
      });     
    return true;
  }
```

Below is the stopImageUpload() function where it displays the cancel message using success and result:

```
function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){
  var result = '';
  if (success == 2){
    result = '<span class="imagecemsg"> The file upload was canceled!</span><br/><br/>';
  } else {
    result = '<span class="imageemsg">There was an error during file upload!</span><br/><br/>';
  }         
  return true;   
}
```

Finally below is the imageupload.php script which is linked to the QandATable.php (The script which contains the code above) using iframe and this is where the database row is suppose to be inserted and deleted from:

```
    <?php
      session_start();
      ...//connected to DB
      $result = 0;

if( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {
    $result = 1;

    $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) 
    VALUES ('ImageFiles/".mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."')";

    mysql_query($imagesql);

}
    else
      {

      $result = 1;

        $imagesql = "INSERT INTO Image (ImageFile) 
        VALUES ('ImageFiles/".mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."')";

mysql_query($imagesql);

      }

      if ($result == 2) {
        $imagecancelsql = "DELETE FROM Image 
                           WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/".
                           mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES['fileImage']['name'])."'";
        mysql_query($imagecancelsql);
      }
      mysql_close();
    ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">window.top.stopImageUpload(<?php echo $result ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>, '<?php echo $_FILES['fileImage']['name'] ?>');</script>
```

Comment: Try adding an asterix? It should be obvious, but when setting $result to zero, how exactly do you expect it to be 2 on the next row?

Comment: That is where the problem is. How can I get it to determine that when the success = 2 in javascript, that I can somehow use $result in php to match this number to then be able to perform it's delete db row command

Comment: Guys, this is what I want to do if you look at code above. At moment if the user clicks on the "Upload" button, it inserts a database row consisting of the file name which is working well. But if the user clicks on the "Cancel" button while file is uploading, then I want it to delete the database row consisting of the file name but this isn't working

Comment: Sorry, uploads don't work that way. You don't cancel in the middle of an upload and have the script on the server suddenly stop and do something else. The server-side script doesn't run until the upload is finished anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are severe issues with your code that need to be addressed:

**1)**

This line:

```
return stopImageUpload(2);
```

Is calling the function:

```
function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){...}
```

But the `stopImageUpload` function needs two parameters, `success` and `imagefilename`

---

**2)**

This function returns true, but should return the contents of `result`.

```
function stopImageUpload(success, imagefilename){
  ...
  return true;   
}
```

---

**3)**

Here you set `$result` with the value `0`, and compare it with the value `2` ?!?

```
$result = 0;

if ($result == 2) {
```

---

**4)**

This function accepts two parameters, but none of them is used inside ?!?

```
function startImageUpload(imageuploadform, imagefilename){...}
```

Also, it is returning

```
return stopImageUpload(2);
```

or

```
return true;
```

Are you controlling this situation!

**Note:** Where do you use this function ?!?

---

**5)**

This verification likely fails because `file_exists` checks whether a file or directory exists. So, if the file does not exist, surely the directory does, and it will continue to execute.

```
if( file_exists("ImageFiles/".$_FILES['fileImage']['name'])) {
```

you should use [is_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) that tells you if the file is a regular file.

---

**6)**

You should not be using `mysql_query` anymore, please read [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

<strike>`mysql_query($imagesql)`</strike>

---

### Please read this topics: <sup>to learn why are you failing to achieve your goal</sup>

[PHP Variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

[JavaScript Variables](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp)

[JavaScript Functions](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/function.html)

[PHP File Upload e.g. 1](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) | [PHP File Upload e.g. 2](http://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_upload_file.cfm) | [PHP File Upload e.g. 3](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)

---

I hope this may help you getting on the right track and fixing some issues with your present code.

*Best of Luck!*